# How to edit Menu primary nav tab in Drupal 8

Tags: 8

Page contains two nav bars with primary having View, Edit, Notes, Resend, Devel tabs and a secondary nav bar with Definition, Render, Load, Tokens. I am using css to not display particular tabs in primary and totally hiding the secondary nav bar. But, one of the requirement is to edit the name of a tab. I tried using theme_preprocess_menu_local_task hook but I am not able to edit the protected object values. What is the approach I need to take to edit the name of the tab. In this case 'resend' to 'forward'.

```
    function theme_preprocess_menu_local_task(&$variables) { 
     if($variables['item']->text =='Resend'){
        $variables['item']->text = 'Forward';
     } 
    }
```

the above code bombs with error saying protected values cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wish to use [hook_local_tasks_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_local_tasks_alter/8.6.x) and/or [hook_menu_local_tasks_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21menu.api.php/function/hook_menu_local_tasks_alter/8.6.x) to hide/rename local tasks.

Comment: Thanks for the info...I created a new custom module and implemented the hook_menu_local_tasks_alter and I am able to rename a tab. But is this the best solution. I am creating a new custom module just to rename a tab, I cant do it in an existing custom theme.

Comment: We usually have at least one custom module in any of our sites that is able to implement hooks or deal with other customizations not provided by Core or contributed modules. You can do a lot out-of-the-box and also in your theme. But not everything.